# Is my proof for $\sup(A) \le \sup(B)$ if $A \subseteq B$ correct?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose $A$ and B are sets such that $A \subseteq B$. Now suppose $\sup(A)$ and $\sup(B)$ exist and $\sup(A) = M$ and $\sup(B) = N$. Therefore, we have that $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists x \in A \space M - \epsilon < x < M$ and $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists y \in B \space N - \epsilon < y < N$. For the sake of contradiction, suppose $\sup(A) > \sup(B)$. Since $M > N$ and $M - \epsilon > N - \epsilon$ it follows that $\exists x \in A \space \forall y \in B \space x > y$. However, since $A \subseteq B$ we can find a $y \in B$ such that $y = x$, which contradicts the fact that $\exists x \in A \space \forall y \in B \space x > y$. Therefore, $\sup(A) \le \sup(B)$.

Comment: I think you meant $\cdots y\in B\,N-\cdots$ no?(near the start)

Comment: @holo Ya i did, sorry about that

Comment: it is still $x$ at this line

Comment: sorry, fixed it.

Comment: Your proof is good and I'd give full credit.  It's cumbersome and the "language" is hard to read. Others showed you how to be more direct and elegant by direct definitions.  It'd be good to emulate that.  But elequence and clarity is an art, not a science, and it comes with practice and experience.  Your proof and math... is correct.

Comment: @fleablood I think your comment should be the accepted answer. Cheers.

Comment: No, my answer was in response to those (especially yours) showed it could be made more simple by direct definitions.  The thing is, better proofs may exist but the OP showed s/he understood the concept and although s/he struggled through it and didn't realize it was a lot *easier* than s/he thought, she understood what needed to be expressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditions on $M$ are that

1. for all $x\in A$, $x\le M$
2. for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $x\in A$ such that $M-\varepsilon<x$

Note the $\le$ sign and the difference in quantifiers. You cannot say in general that from $x\in A$ it follows that $x<M$: think to $M=\{0\}$, whose supremum is obviously $0$.

Your idea to go by contradiction is good (but you could avoid it). However $M-\varepsilon>N-\varepsilon$ does not imply so directly that there is $x\in A$ so that $x>y$ for every $y\in B$. For one thing: what's $\varepsilon$? You have to *pick one*, precisely $\varepsilon=M-N$. Here's how you can fix the rest of the proof.

From $M>N$ it follows that $\varepsilon=M-N>0$ and therefore there exists $x\in A$ with
$$
x>M-\varepsilon=M-(M-N)=N
$$
from property 2 applied to $A$; from property 1 applied to $B$, we know that $y\le N$, for every $y\in B$. Therefore, for every $y\in B$ we have $y\le N<x$ and so $y<x$. Thus $x\notin B$: a contradiction.

Note 1. Saying “since $A\subseteq B$ we can find a $y\in B$ such that $y=x$” is a very convoluted form of saying that $x\in B$.

Note 2. If the supremum of $B$ is $\infty$, then of course $\sup(A)\le\sup(B)$, so you can assume $\sup(B)$ is finite. If $\sup(A)=\infty$, then it cannot be that $\sup(B)$ is finite, because for every $K$ there exists $x\in A$ (hence $x\in B$) with $x>K$.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there are 2 issues with your proof: it relies on the finiteness of the suprema and it's unnecessarily complicated. You can work directly from definition:
$$
\sup B\geq x,\forall x\in B\implies \sup B\geq x,\forall x\in A\implies\sup B\geq \sup A.
$$
The first implication uses $A\subset B$ and second uses the definition of supremum.

Comment: Wow, your proof is much nicer. I just have one question though: how come my proof relies on finiteness?

Comment: For example, $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists x \in A \space M - \epsilon < x < M$ is not true for $M=\infty$.

Comment: But if sup(A) exists, can M still be infinity? I always thought that if sup(A) equals infinity, the supremum does not exist.

Comment: @BeepBoop I'm not sure which convention you follow, but since your problem is stated quite succinctly, I'm allowing, for example, $\sup(A)$ to be $\infty$ when $A$ is not bounded from above. See for example: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125b/ch2.pdf. In any case, even if we impose that $\sup(A),\sup(B)<\infty$, your argument can be simplified as above. There is no reason to bring up $\epsilon$ or to do a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Most text would say for the sup to exist that  the set must be bounded from above.  Otherwise the sup simply will not exist.  Most texts would consider a sup = $\infty$ to be an oxymoron.  I think the OP statement suppose sup A and sup B exist is acceptable to assume they are finite.

Comment: In other words.  It depends on your text.  Kim Jong Un follows a convention that if a set is not bounded above we can state $\sup M =\infty$  This can be convenient.  The OP clearly follows a convention that if a set is bounded above then it has upper limits and if there is a least upper limit it is the sup.  This is technical and clear.  In either case you *must* acknowledge whether a sup exists in the first place.  If your space has the least upper bound property (aka is "complete") then all upper bounded set will have a sup.  .... to be cont....

Comment: ... If you are in a complete space (such as $\mathbb R$ as opposed to $\mathbb Q$) then for all upper bounded sets, the $\sup$ exists. This is when Kim Jong Un's convention becomes *very* convenient.  $\sup$ will *always* exist and "$\sup A$ is finite" becomes a simple way of saying "$A$ is bounded above".  IMO I prefer *not* to use Kim Jong Un's convention unless we are talking about the extended real numbers in which case $\infty$ is considered to be an element.  I find it inaccurate and confusing.  But that's just my opinion.  But I will grant it is convenient.